# How to arrange titles around a `oval` shape by `even` and `odd` values based

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working in `angular` application. i have a scenario here, when i am getting the titles from back-end the client requires that to be arranged around a `oval` (it contains some image)

and when the tiles length are `odd` then the firs element ( balance ) should be in the top. rest of the titles need to arrange the both side of the `oval`.

when i am getting the title length as `even` there is no need to keep the title in the top.

i tried some point. but i didn't get any valuable output.

my be the way i am doing (`directive`) is wrong? or this should be handle with some other way?

any one help me to find the mathematical logic here please?

[image: Here is what i am looking for my out put as!]

**click the bottom button to create random titles**

[Live Demo of my try](http://plnkr.co/edit/FvoWnMpnljBHyhGHTqdD?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want something like this:

```js
var radiusX = 250,
    radiusY = 100,
    texts = [],
    oval = document.getElementById('oval'),
    inp = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  texts.push(inp.value);
  inp.value = '';
  while(oval.firstChild) oval.removeChild(oval.firstChild);
  texts.forEach(function(text, i, arr){
    var angle = Math.PI + (i*2 + 1 - arr.length%2) * Math.PI / arr.length;
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.style.top = radiusY + Math.cos(angle) * radiusY + 'px';
    el.style.left = radiusX -Math.sin(angle) * radiusX + 'px';
    el.textContent = text;
    oval.appendChild(el);
  });
};
```

```css
#oval {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#oval > div {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 1.2;
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 3em;
  margin-top: -.6em;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input id="text" placeholder="Write text..."/>
<button>Add text</button>
<div id="oval"></div>
```

Basically, divide `2 * Math.PI` (360deg) into `n` equal angles, where `n` is the number of texts.

Then use `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` on that angle, and multiply it by the horizontal or vertical radius of the ellipse. That will give the coordinates relatively to the center of the ellipse.