# Using `Math.PI` how to set my own value of angles in each element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

How do I set an array of values (degrees) to an element?

Each element needs to take values from the array and need to arrange accordingly. For me it's not working. Can any one show me the correct way to do this?

Example code:

```
var items = 4;
var values = [0,15,30,45] //first should be 0, next 15deg like so..
for(var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    var num = i;
    var x = 75 - 12 + 87 * Math.cos(values[i]);
    var y = 75 - 12 + 87 * Math.sin(values[i]); 

    $("#center").append("<div class='point' style='left:"+ x +"px;top:"+ y +"px'></div>");   
}
```

At some point if I require to set 360 elements, that should arrange according to the array values for example.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jE26S/372/)

Comment: Did';t you ask this a couple of hours ago? did you delete it?

Comment: look at the css3 transforms.

Comment: is the question how to plot an element at a particular degree of a circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle you pass to `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` must be in radians, not degrees.

To convert to radians, just multiply your angles by `Math.PI / 180`.

```js
var values = [0,15,30,45];
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  $(document.createElement('div')).css({
    left: 75 - 12 + 87 * Math.cos(values[i] * Math.PI / 180),
    top: 75 - 12 + 87 * Math.sin(values[i] * Math.PI / 180)
  }).addClass('point').appendTo("#center");    
}
```

```css
.point {
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="center"></div>
```

Comment: It works fine. if you have any thought about this question as well, appreciated much. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070130/how-to-arrange-titles-around-a-oval-shape-by-even-and-odd-values-based